# Bundle install is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, gemfile

I'm developing Ruby on Rails on Windows.

Something went wrong with our local network and can't access https://www.rubygems.org, seems like it is blocked or something.

But I can access it through http://www.proxyfoxy.com.

Below is the result of `bundle install`:

> $ bundle install
>
> Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Is there any other way to install gems through `bundle install`?

Comment: seems like it's your network issue rather than `rubygems.org`

Comment: let us know if you can visit other websites in natural way without any proxy

Comment: visit here (http://isitup.org/rubygems.org)  to make sure the issue is local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a connectivity issue.

I solved it through [hideMe VPN](https://hide.me/en/proxy). It is used to bypass blocked websites or for servers down only for a particular user.

Now everything seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 14):

Open the Gemfile and change first line from this

```
source 'https://www.rubygems.org'
```

to this

```
source 'http://www.rubygems.org'
```

remove the '`s`' from '`https`'.

Comment: @soorapadman this isn't a link only answer. Please read it more thoroughly. ACHYUT KADAM is suggesting to change the line `source 'https://www.rubygems.org'`.

Comment: @CaptainMan my bad apologies.

Comment: Well, I had a similar issue with Ruby 1.9.3 (required due to a certain system), and this actually worked. It complained a lot about MITM etc, but it did work

Answer (score 8):

As @Wasif mentioned, first make sure the [Ruby Gems](https://www.rubygems.org/) site is up and your network access is ok.

If they works fine, try it like this:

- First, delete your `Gemfile.lock` file
- Then run `gem update --system`
- Then in your Gemfile try changing the first line `source
  'https://rubygems.org'`to `http://` (without an `s`)

Unless there is a problem with your connectivity this should fix the issue with `bundle install`.

Comment: It's a connectivity issue.I solved it through hideMe VPN.  it is used to bypass blocked websites or for servers down only for a particular user.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, 
Your DNS cause this problem.

You can change your DNS to `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8`

#### Instructions for mac

- Go to preferences panel
- Click on network panel
- Click to advanced button
- Go to DNS tab
- Add DNS server (with '+' button)
- Enter `1.1.1.1` OR `8.8.8.8`
- Click to Ok
- And click to apply

But you can follow these steps:
http://www.macinstruct.com/node/434

#### Instructions for windows

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

While gem is stalling, I ran **netstat**

```
netstat -tnp | grep ruby
```

and I got below output

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      1 2401:4900:188e:90:56960 2a04:4e42:600::644:443  SYN_SENT    4096/ruby
```

and 2a04:4e42:600::644:443 is one of the addresses of api.rubygems.org

My conclusion is that gem uses IPv6 when it can.

**So disabling IPV6 on my workstation fixed it.**

Below are the steps to temporarily disabled IPV6 on Ubuntu. IPV6 will be enabled after system restart.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

Note: Use sudo for `permission denied` issue.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/206345)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it happened to work when I shutdown the rails server before running `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue but on Ubuntu, what helped was running:

```
env | grep proxy
```

which showed some active proxies like these:

```
https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
```

After I removed each of them with the unset command:

```
unset https_proxy
unset http_proxy
```

I could run `bundle install` normally.

Answer (score 1):

This mistake was very difficult for me. I was a day without being able to solve it but finally I turned off my wifi router and waited 1 minute to turn it on again. Then the error was fixed, hope it helps.

Comment: This is weird. But it worked for me. Turn the internet off and on again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when running `bundle` in a rails app. I solve the problem by running:

```
$ bin/bundle
```

Problem was that `bundle` was v1.17.3, while `bin/bundle` was version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a network issue.

follwoing things can help you to solve this problem -:

1. forget the network and reconnect it.
2. Turn on aeroplane mode of your mobile and again turn off it if you connected with mobile hotspot

Answer (score 0):

Someone might find this useful: I had this error message when building a docker image and it turned out I had some custom dns settings in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Answer (score -1):

In your Gemfile from the first line the source should be http:// instead of https://

change

`sourçe  https://www.rubygems.org` into

`source  http://www.rubygems.org`

Then you can run `bundle install` successfully

Answer (score -2):

It's a connectivity issue.I solved it through hideMe VPN. it is used to bypass blocked websites or for servers down only for a particular user